# how can you see av_dump_format print messsage in android logcat

Tags: android, ffmpeg, logcat

i am just wondering...

how can you see av_dump_format print messsage in android logcat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, You need to enable the log in your `Android.mk` or `CMakeLists.txt` file

If you are using NDK build, then add

```
LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -llog
```

to your `Android.mk` file.

OR

If you are using CMake build, then first find the log library using

```
find_library( # Defines the name of the path variable that stores the
              # location of the NDK library.
              log_lib

              # Specifies the name of the NDK library that
              # CMake needs to locate.
              log )
```

and then link the log library to your target library like this

```
target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
                       YOUR_LIB_NAME

                       # Links the log library to the target library.
                       ${log_lib} )
```

Once you are done linking the log library to your native build, do the following things.

- Add `#include "android/log.h"` on top of the file.
- Define a macro to print the log like this

`#define print_log(LOG_LEVEL, TAG, ...) __android_log_print(LOG_LEVEL, TAG, __VA_ARGS__)`

- Create a `Callback` function to your native class with a specific method signature

```
static void callback(void *ptr, int level, const char *fmt, va_list vl)
{
    if (level > av_log_get_level())
        return;

    va_list vl2;
    char line[1024];
    static int print_prefix = 1;

    va_copy(vl2, vl);
    av_log_format_line(ptr, level, fmt, vl2, line, sizeof(line), &print_prefix);
    va_end(vl2);

    print_log(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "FFMPEG", "%s", line);
}
```

- Set the level of log you want to receive `av_log_set_level(32);`
- Set the log callback by calling `av_log_set_callback(callback);`

You can take decision from the level whether you want to print the log as `INFO, ERROR, WARNING or VERVOSE` from the `level`.

**Build** the app and **run** the command

`ffmpeg -hide_banner -i /storage/emulated/0/input.mp4`

You should see something like this in the logcat.

```
2020-04-03 11:41:49.154 25142-25259/com.example.ffmpeg I/FFMPEG: Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/storage/emulated/0/input.mp4':
2020-04-03 11:41:49.154 25142-25259/com.example.ffmpeg I/FFMPEG:   Metadata:
2020-04-03 11:41:49.154 25142-25259/com.example.ffmpeg I/FFMPEG:     major_brand     : 
2020-04-03 11:41:49.154 25142-25259/com.example.ffmpeg I/FFMPEG: isom
2020-04-03 11:41:49.154 25142-25259/com.example.ffmpeg I/FFMPEG:     minor_version   : 
2020-04-03 11:41:49.154 25142-25259/com.example.ffmpeg I/FFMPEG: 512
2020-04-03 11:41:49.155 25142-25259/com.example.ffmpeg I/FFMPEG:     compatible_brands: 
2020-04-03 11:41:49.155 25142-25259/com.example.ffmpeg I/FFMPEG: isomiso2avc1mp41
2020-04-03 11:41:49.155 25142-25259/com.example.ffmpeg I/FFMPEG:     encoder         : 
2020-04-03 11:41:49.155 25142-25259/com.example.ffmpeg I/FFMPEG: Lavf57.83.100
2020-04-03 11:41:49.155 25142-25259/com.example.ffmpeg I/FFMPEG:   Duration: 
2020-04-03 11:41:49.155 25142-25259/com.example.ffmpeg I/FFMPEG: 00:00:58.10
2020-04-03 11:41:49.155 25142-25259/com.example.ffmpeg I/FFMPEG: , start: 
2020-04-03 11:41:49.155 25142-25259/com.example.ffmpeg I/FFMPEG: 0.000000
2020-04-03 11:41:49.155 25142-25259/com.example.ffmpeg I/FFMPEG: , bitrate: 
2020-04-03 11:41:49.155 25142-25259/com.example.ffmpeg I/FFMPEG: 3716 kb/s
2020-04-03 11:41:49.155 25142-25259/com.example.ffmpeg I/FFMPEG:     Stream #0:0
2020-04-03 11:41:49.155 25142-25259/com.example.ffmpeg I/FFMPEG: (und)
2020-04-03 11:41:49.155 25142-25259/com.example.ffmpeg I/FFMPEG: : Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1080x1350, 3588 kb/s
2020-04-03 11:41:49.155 25142-25259/com.example.ffmpeg I/FFMPEG: , 
2020-04-03 11:41:49.155 25142-25259/com.example.ffmpeg I/FFMPEG: 29.99 fps, 
2020-04-03 11:41:49.155 25142-25259/com.example.ffmpeg I/FFMPEG: 29.97 tbr, 
2020-04-03 11:41:49.155 25142-25259/com.example.ffmpeg I/FFMPEG: 1000k tbn, 
2020-04-03 11:41:49.155 25142-25259/com.example.ffmpeg I/FFMPEG: 2000k tbc
2020-04-03 11:41:49.155 25142-25259/com.example.ffmpeg I/FFMPEG:  (default)
2020-04-03 11:41:49.155 25142-25259/com.example.ffmpeg I/FFMPEG:     Metadata:
2020-04-03 11:41:49.155 25142-25259/com.example.ffmpeg I/FFMPEG:       handler_name    : 
2020-04-03 11:41:49.155 25142-25259/com.example.ffmpeg I/FFMPEG: VideoHandler
2020-04-03 11:41:49.155 25142-25259/com.example.ffmpeg I/FFMPEG:     Stream #0:1
2020-04-03 11:41:49.155 25142-25259/com.example.ffmpeg I/FFMPEG: (und)
2020-04-03 11:41:49.155 25142-25259/com.example.ffmpeg I/FFMPEG: : Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 124 kb/s
2020-04-03 11:41:49.155 25142-25259/com.example.ffmpeg I/FFMPEG:  (default)
2020-04-03 11:41:49.155 25142-25259/com.example.ffmpeg I/FFMPEG:     Metadata:
2020-04-03 11:41:49.155 25142-25259/com.example.ffmpeg I/FFMPEG:       handler_name    : 
2020-04-03 11:41:49.155 25142-25259/com.example.ffmpeg I/FFMPEG: SoundHandler
2020-04-03 11:41:49.155 25142-25259/com.example.ffmpeg I/FFMPEG: At least one output file must be specified
2020-04
```